# Автоматический remount удалённой Windows файловой системы в Linux

Tags: linux, mount

Есть удалённая ФС под ОС Windows, есть ПК под Linux (Ubuntu). Основная проблема заключается в том, что удалённая ФС периодически "отваливается" (в Linux системе она остаётся примонтированной, но при попытке обратиться к этому узлу выводится сообщение о том, что узел отключен). Возможно, это нормальное поведение. Лечится перемонтированием.

Монтирую следующим скриптом:

```
mount.cifs //10.1.0.101/DFS /home/accumplus/common/dfs -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,workgroup=MOSCOW,credentials=/home/accumplus/.secret/smb
```

При выполнении этой строки "руками" от рута - всё монтируется замечательно.

Написал правило в crontab, которое должно выполнять скрипт с этой строкой (делал от рута, здесь ошибки быть не должно быть). Скрипт выполняется, но при монтировании выводится ошибка 127 Key has expired. Беглый гуглинг показал, что надо менять пароль на удалённой системе, но я считаю, что проблема не в этом, так как монтирование вручную работает (да и к тому же у меня нет прав для смены пароля на удалённом сервере).

Прошу помощи в решении данной проблемы!

Comment: может быть из-за того, что слишком часто пытается смонтировать, отвергается ключ?

Comment: Вообще, это очень странно. У меня самба-шары при восстановлении связи отлично возобновляют свои сессии. Так что лучше разбирайтесь с тем, как именно оно отваливается и почему. До кучи рекомендую проверить права и окружение у того, что запускается от рута/крона. И перед перемонтированием, лучше предыдущее монтирование демонтировать, а то так и будет висеть сотня-другая активных сессий.

Comment: @bukkojot я демонтируют разумеется. Тогда буду разбираться, как оно отваливается и почему) спасибо

Comment: @SeniorPomidor как вариант конечно рассмотреть стоит. Но руками то я могу сколько угодно раз монтировать.